# How I can round up values in Polars

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

I have some calculated float columns. I want to display values of one column rounded, but `round(pl.col("value"), 2)` not vorking properly in Polars. How I can make it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```py
df.with_column(
    pl.col("x").round(2)
)
```

Comment: Big thanx! I can't find it myself)

Comment: Yes thank you...the polars docs are a little confusing considering their organization but here is the cite:
https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.round.html